# How to refresh kubernetes config access-token in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker, google-kubernetes-engine

how to refresh token in gcloud or GKE cluster in spinnaker

```
kubeconfig expaires after 1 hour, how to refresh token in gcloud or GKE cluster in spinnaker
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more information; edit your question and make it better by adding steps you have tried, error, logs etc

Comment: Created GKE-cluster in kubernetes engine,able get pods in gcloud, but i want  to get pods from non gcloud vm. i copied kube/config file to new vm, when query kubectl get pods , getting pods , after 1 hour or so kube/config expaired, then need to update again new cofig from gke-cluster.  i want to update token in out side .Access Kubernetes GKE cluster outside of GKE cluster ?

Comment: after 1hour i got error like    Unable to connect to the server: error executing access token command "/google/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud config config-helper --format=json": err=fork/exec /google/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud: no such file or directory output= stderr=

Comment: Thanks for replaying ...@ Alioua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a known issue, could you try updating the credential file using the following [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/get-credentials):

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials NAME [--region=REGION     | --zone=ZONE, -z ZONE] [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]
```

This Github [thread](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2277#issuecomment-297146144) suggested the above solution and it worked for other users. Additionally review this [thread](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2249#issuecomment-294793552) to get an overview of this issue.